# Hangfire allow just one server

Tags: asp.net, hangfire

We have an Azure Scale Out resource, the problem is: For each instance, Hangfire launch a new server, any way to limit to one server only?

Comment: Just don't start the server then? Or deploy the server in a separate application that you only deploy one of?

Comment: How to determine if there is a Hangfire running? Any api method? SQL Server select? Tks

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using Sql Server storage, which seems to be the case, you can do:

```
 GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.UseSqlServerStorage("YourDB");
        var servers = Hangfire.SqlServer.SqlServerStorage.Current
                                                         .GetMonitoringApi()
                                                         .Servers();
        if (servers != null && servers.Count < 1)
            //start new server here;
```

Comment: I'm in a similar situation. This solution will work to cap instances, however it seems like this could get you into a scenario where - depending on which instances App Services decides to scale back, you may end up running only on instances with no Hangfire server running. So if you Scale Out and Scale In, and only start Hangfire servers on App Start, then keep that in mind.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround for this problem was: Check on SQLServer if there is an active Hangfire server:

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(myConnString))
                {
                    SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(LastHeartBeat) FROM HangFire.Server";
                    connection.Open();
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.SingleResult))
                    {
                        if (reader.HasRows)
                        {
                            reader.Read();
                            DateTime lastBeat = reader.GetDateTime(0);
                            bool myResult = lastBeat >= DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(-2);
                        }
                    }
                }
```